# Multiple relation n:n to one table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize for PostgresSQL. For example: I've got two tables `Friendship` and `User`. To make friendship possible for every user, I've got two relations n:n.

**Associations in Sequelize**

```
User.hasMany(Friendship,
  {
    as: "friendshipsAsked",
    foreignKey: "asked_user_id",
    joinTableName: "friendship"
  });

User.hasMany(Friendship,
  {
    as: "friendshipsAsking",
    foreignKey:  "asking_user_id",
    joinTableName: "friendship"
  });

Friendship.belongsTo(User,
  {
    ...
  });

Friendship.belongsTo(User,
  {
    ...
  });
```

My biggest problem is querying friendships for user. When I've got user model, I have to get `user.getFriendshipsAsking()` and `user.getFriendshipsAsked()` and then merge both.

Is there any possibility to change relations so I can have `user.getFriendships()` in SQL such that it will perform like `SELECT * FROM frienships WHERE requesting_user_id = 'user.id' OR requested_user_id = 'user.id'`?

I would like to have a better solution to model `friendship` between users in the database?